# Required property in pnp/sp PeoplePicker not working

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have question about pnp/sp PeoplePicker.
PeoplePicker has property "required", but wen i use it in my form it is ignored.

This is my PeoplePicker code:

```
<PeoplePicker
required={true}
context={this.props.spContext}
personSelectionLimit={1}
onChange={this.hcRequestorPP}
showHiddenInUI={false}
principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
ensureUser={true}
resolveDelay={1000}
defaultSelectedUsers={this.props.pRequestor}
disabled={false} />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helo,
you are not doing anything wrong :-) Required property based on my knowledge puts asterisk next to people picker label - that's all.

If you want check in the form if user has put something into people picker field, you have to check it by yourself.

My version of form is:

1. every form value is stored in state.
2. every form field with its definition (name, type, required, ...) is stored in props (or state, or const, etc.).
3. before submitting form, I am checking if every required value is filled (code below)
4. if it is not filled I put error message under the field.

good example to start is here: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-list-form

**checking required**

```
let requiredError: boolean = false;
let fieldErrors: { [fieldName: string]: string } = {...this.state.fieldErrors};
// check required
for (let i: number = 0; i < this.state.fieldsSchema.length; i++) {
  if ((this.state.fieldsSchema[i].Required) && (!this.state.data[this.state.fieldsSchema[i].InternalName]) && (this.state.fieldsSchema[i].InternalName !== 'Aktivita')) {
    requiredError = true;
    fieldErrors = {
      ...fieldErrors,
      [this.state.fieldsSchema[i].InternalName]: strings.FormFields.RequiredValueMessage
    };
  }
}
if (requiredError === true) {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    fieldErrors: fieldErrors,
    requiredFieldEmpty: requiredError
  });
  return;
}
```

Comment: Hello Matej, thank you for you anwser. I did something similar, i check it myself. I find this "required" little confusing. Thank you, Matjaz